# Newton-Raphson iteration on a system of non-linear PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, jacobian, newton-raphson

Currently, I am working on a system of non-linear partial integro-differential equations and trying to find stationary solutions numerically. The system can be written as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x;t) = F(f(x;t), l((x,y;t))  \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t} l(x,y;t) = L(f(x;t), l((x,y;t)),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $t$ is the time and $x,y$ are variables contained in a certain set $S$. $f$ and $l$ are unknown, real positive, functions and $F$ and $L$ are expressions containing these functions in multiple terms, amongst others double integral terms. I am struggeling to find out if the Newton-Raphson scheme is a suitable approach for finding stationary solutions.

So far I tried the following:

We write 
$$
\mathbf{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    f(x;t) \\
    l(x,y;t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and
$$
\mathbf{G} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    F(f(x;t), l((x,y;t)) \\
    L(f(x;t), l((x,y;t))
\end{bmatrix}
$$

such that after discretisation
$$
\mathbf{x}^{\tau+1} = \mathbf{x}^\tau - J_{\mathbf{G}}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}^\tau) \cdot \mathbf{G(x^\tau)}
$$
in which,
$$
J_{\mathbf{G}}(\mathbf{x}^\tau) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F(f(x;t), l((x,y;t))}{\partial f(x;t)} & \frac{\partial F(f(x;t), l((x,y;t))}{\partial f(x;t)} \\
\frac{\partial L(f(x;t), l((x,y;t))}{\partial l((x,y;t)}& \frac{\partial L(f(x;t), l((x,y;t))}{\partial l((x,y;t)}
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$

Here I am getting stuck. How are these derivatives of an expression to a function defined (if they exist)? And maybe more general,  does it make sense to find stationairy solutions this way?

**Addition:**

Would it be an idea to use 
$$
\frac{\partial F(f(x;t),l(x,y;t))}{\partial f(x;t)} = \frac{\partial F(f(x;t),l(x,y;t))}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial f(x;t)} + \frac{\partial F(f(x;t),l(x,y;t))}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial f(x;t)}
= \frac{\partial F(f(x;t),l(x,y;t))}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f(x;t)}{\partial x}^{-1} + \frac{\partial F(f(x;t),l(x,y;t))}{\partial t} \frac{\partial f(x;t)}{\partial t}^{-1}$$
Under what assumptions is this valid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually you would discretise your PDE first using finite difference methods, then find the root of the resulting equation.

Comment: I do have the PDE's in discretised form, I only omitted them in this post since they are quite elaborate. Still for finding the root one needs the evaluated Jacobian. That is where I am stuck. How are the derivatives in the Jacobian defined/calculated?